# Is it possible to go to the "next page" of search results in mu4e?

Tags: mu4e

Say you have searched or opened any header view. It will show the `mu4e-search-results-limit` number of search results, defaulting to 500.

My question is: Once I reach the end of these results; is it possible to continue to the next 500 results in any way, to go the next page so to speak? This without increasing the value of `mu4e-search-results-limit`.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think there is a way of fetching and displaying something like matches between 500 to 1000 (`mu find` only has the possibility to set a `maxnum` limit). A workaround is to temporarily extend
`mu4e-search-results-limit` and display more and more matches, for a kind of incremental paging. If search and display are already slow, this obviously will grow slower and slower. The following implements that approach:

```
(defvar my-mu4e-page 1 "Current page in mu4e search.")

(defun my-mu4e-reset-page (&rest _r)
  "Reset ‘my-mu4e-page’ to 1."
  (setq my-mu4e-page 1))

;; We need to reset it for the "standard searches", but also when
;; invoking an interactive search
(add-hook 'mu4e-search-bookmark-hook #'my-mu4e-reset-page)
(advice-add 'mu4e-search-maildir :before #'my-mu4e-reset-page)

(defun my-mu4e-next-messages-for-query ()
  "Fetch the next number of messages for current mu4e query.
Move to last message in current view so that newly fetched
messages are visible."
  (interactive)
  (when (and (mu4e-current-buffer-type-p 'headers)
             (not mu4e-headers-full-search))
    (when-let ((query (mu4e-last-query)))
      (cl-incf my-mu4e-page)
      (let ((mu4e-search-results-limit
             (* my-mu4e-page mu4e-search-results-limit))
            (last-msg (save-excursion
                        (goto-char (point-max))
                        (forward-line -1)
                        (plist-get
                         (mu4e-message-at-point)
                         :message-id))))
        (mu4e-search query nil nil t last-msg)))))

(keymap-set mu4e-headers-mode-map "N" #'my-mu4e-next-messages-for-query)
```